# How to migrate Postman Environments to Karate?

Tags: karate

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension#postman-import shows how to import a postman collection to Karate.

Is there a way to add a postman_environment.json (https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/managing-environments/) to the karate importer so that all the variables, that are used in a collection, are configured properly in karate? (supposedly in the karate-config.js)

Comment: this is not supported right now

Comment: thanks for the rapid response  Is such a feature on the roadmap?

Comment: if you have an urgent enterprise need for this, we can look at expediting this. feel free to use our contact form: https://www.karatelabs.io/contact-us